# How to prevent scroll event overlap with scrollIntoView() scroll- behavior: smooth?

Tags: javascript

I’m relying on a very basic use of `scrollIntoView() scroll-behavior:smooth` to ensure the current line of a multi-line text  is scrolled along with a user’s typing in a different input.

The issue is if a user types very fast or types short phrases, scrollIntoView() can be called multiple times before the previous scrollIntoView() action completes. This results in a jittery visual scrolling effect due to the easing of the scroll-behavior:smooth.

How can I repeatedly call `scrollIntoView() scroll-behavior:smooth` but have it only engage if the previous scroll has completed and is no longer in action?